# A game with dice: counting some probabilities

Tags: probability

Alice and Bob have one fair die each, and they play the following game. At each round they simultaneously toss their dice: if none of them gets a 6 they move to the next round, and otherwise whoever gets a 6 wins and the game ends. Note that there could be a tie, if they both get a 6.

1. What is the probability that the game end in the first round?

My answer:

$$
p(END)=11/36
$$
by counting all the pairs where a 6 occurs.

2. What is the probability that the game lasts exactly k rounds, for $k \ge 1$?
3. What is the expected duration of the game?
4. What is the probability that the game ends up in a tie?

What about the three remaining questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability the game lasts exactly one round you already answered.  The probability the game lasts exactly two rounds?  Well... that is going to happen if it doesn't end on the first round and does end on the second round.  That is... for the first round, one of the $25$ other outcomes where no sixes show occurs followed by in the second round one of the $11$ outcomes where at least one six *does* occur.

Handwaving the notation a bit, that would be:

$$\Pr(X=2)=\Pr((no,yes))=\frac{25}{36}\cdot\frac{11}{36}$$

Similarly, for ending after exactly three rounds that would be the game did not end on the first round, did not end on the second round, and did end on the third round.

$$\Pr(X=3)=\Pr((no,no,yes))=\frac{25}{36}\cdot\frac{25}{36}\cdot\frac{11}{36}$$

You should be able to spot a pattern here.

> $$\Pr(X=k)=\left(\frac{25}{36}\right)^{k-1}\cdot\frac{11}{36}$$

This is a quintessential example of a [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

The expected duration of a geometrically distributed random variable is well known.

> It is $\frac{1}{p}$ where $p$ is the chance for success, so here it is $\frac{36}{11}$

As for the probability the game ends in a tie... we can condition our calculations based on the fact that the game *ended* and focus solely on the final round.  There are eleven different outcomes of the final round, each of those eleven outcomes being equally likely.  Only one of those resulted in a tie.

> $$\frac{1}{11}$$